# Unable to get left property value to execute in animate method

Tags: jquery

I have a carousel with a few thumbnail images, and when the user clicks one its suppose to fade out a larger image to the left, then fade back in from the left with the new image. I believe my syntax is correct, and it fades in and out as expected, but not to the left as I want. Below is the jQuery for the click event.

```
// click event handler for the <a> elements
$("#image_list a").click(function(evt) {
    var lgURL = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#image").animate({ opacity: 0, left: -205 }, 1000,
        function () {
            $("#image").attr("src", lgURL);
            $(this).animate({ opacity: 1, left: "+=205" }, 1000)
        }
    ); //end animate

    evt.preventDefault();
}); //end click
```

Comment: You did position the element and set a default left value in CSS.

Comment: Which version of jQuery do you use? In `1.10.0` they have accidentally broken the relative animations (e.g. `+=`) which was fixed in `1.10.1` again.

Comment: I'm using the latest CDN!

Answer (score 2):

Try using a number value for the left instead of a string.

Since you're wanting to add 205, why not just set the left to 0?

`$(this).animate({ opacity: 1, left: 0 }, 1000)`

Comment: Cant set it to 0 because it has a margin-left: 105px

Answer (score 0):

The reason the effect wasn't taking place was that I did not specify a position of relative to the element. After I updated my CSS the animation effect of it fading to the left, then back in from the left worked like a charm.

```
#image {
position: relative;
height: 250px;
margin-bottom: 1em; 
margin-left: 105px;
}
```